# Is it possible to have an account login more than once to Windows Server 2k3 VPN (RRAS)?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rras

I'm creating an account for one of our support vendors to be able to login to VPN on our Windows 2003 AD domain. There may be multiple engineers logging in to the network, so is there a way to have a single account that can login multiple times?

Otherwise, I would have to create multiple accounts with slightly different names: i.e. support1, support2, etc.

Comment: If there is you'll lose any kind of identity management and accountability you might have hoped for with the vendor. When there's a problem do you want to have to question them as to which "support1" individual is responsible?

Comment: No, I don't need to be able to differentiate. The vendor assigns different departments to the case depending on the issue, so I'll have maybe 2 guys from engineering and 1 guy from R&D on a ticket for 3 users total that all need access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on your VPN solution - the Windows VPN Server does not limit the number of connections by default (and I've never explored it to see if it was optional to do so; I suspect only through some hacks of sorts akin to those that can be done to ensure only one machine can be logged in to per user account).

Third party VPN solutions (like those built in to some routers) may be more restrictive.

Comment: I ran some testing and I was able to get it to log in multiple times without any special config. Thanks for the heads up.